# Chef - Get output of remote_execute resource

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, recipe

Usually I get command outputs in variables like this:
`` res = `find . -name my_script.sh` ``. Then I can parse the output for what I am interested in.

**How can I get the output of a command executed by a `machine_execute` resource ?**

```
machine_execute 'Check IPA status' do
  command 'ipactl status'
  machine 'IPA_Admin_server'
end
```

Comment: In the future if you have a bunch of questions like this, it might be easier to either post on the discourse.chef.io forums or jump on #chef IRC on Freenode.

Comment: Ok, I will. Thank you for answering my questions here :)

Comment: Asking here is fine too, just seems like you were trying to do something where it might be good to get a broader overview of the whole task than SO allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, Chef resources don't generally have outputs. In some cases the support an output API (like the AWS provisioning driver's `aws_object` helpers) but for something like this you would need to get the low-level `Machine` object and call its `execute` method. Take a look at how the resource [is implemented](https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/machine_execute.rb#L19-L31) for an example. You might also want to skip Provisioning's transport layer and use [Train](https://github.com/chef/train) as we are probably going to try and centralize on that library.